# Why is the tip of my PL-259 connector sheared off?

Tags: cables, termination

I recently ordered a cable with a PL-259 termination and when it arrived I saw that the tip of the plug had been sheared off and at first I thought it was defective and went to return it or downgrade the supplier, however, on examining the product page more closely I saw that the plug was actually shown with a sheared off tip.

[image]

What is the purpose of this?

Comment: To make it easier to solder the cable's core to the inside of the connector's tip.

Comment: @star how does it make it easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the way they are manufactured. It makes them easier to connect and facilitates the soldering process. You will find many variations of this but most I have seen have the angle or notch on the tip. I have seen some that are flat across and the solder ball on the tip makes it easier to connect. You can do a google search for pl259 and look at the images to get an idea of the variety available.

Comment: Is there a more detailed reason on why an angle cut tip makes it easier to solder?